# How create a project with JSF 2 + Eclipse Java EE Web Developers + Hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsf, jboss

I really need to create a simple project with these technologies, I already know how create a JSF 2 project in Eclipse.
But I don't know how to insert hibernate and make it work.
I know in Netbeans but I want to change to Eclipse definitely.

I searched in Google but nothing solid.

Any lead, tip, will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) as in "Good ol' [Hibernate Core](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/)" as it was back then in old J2EE ages or are you talking about Hibernate's JPA implementation, the [`EntityManager`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/)?

If the former, I've found the [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) Eclipse plugin very useful. It allows for autogeneration of entities out of tables and vice versa and offers several useful wizards. Given the fact that you're using JSF2 and based on your question history I know that you're using Java EE 6, I wonder why you wouldn't go for JPA?

If the latter, just use Eclipse's own [Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) plugin (which is already part of Eclipse for Java EE). It offers simliar features as Hibernate Tools. You should now only focus on keyword "JPA", not "Hibernate" as that's now just an implementation detail (the competitor being [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/), which is the reference implementation and used in among others Glassfish). The Dali homepage has good documentation, tutorials and video demos.

Comment: so you think is better use JPA with JSF 2 ? Do you know any good tutorial for it ? Thanks for the tip anyway dude =)

Comment: The old Hibernate Core was great back then in J2EE ages. A lot of lessons have been learnt to design JPA which was added to Java EE. JPA is basically an evolution of Hibernate which is standardized as part of Java EE. You should definitely continue with JPA and not fiddle with old APIs. As to tutorials, just walk through some of those Dali tutorials to generate entities and DAO-like classes, play/test around with them. Then make them EJBs and inject them in your JSF managed beans.